# PHPExcel changes xls DATETIME to numbers

Tags: php, phpexcel, xls

When i upload a .xls file to PHPExcel i´d like to read the raw data.
I read about using "getValue()" and it should fix it.
But not in my case.

So in .xls i have a column: 2015-10-08 11:31
When i process it with PHPExcel i got: 42285.47993055556

Because of PHPExcel reading the file first, i cannot use PHP to make a DATETIME object?!

**PHP**

```
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
$val=array();
    for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
        $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
        $val[] = $cell->getValue();
```

How do i solve this?

**Threw the accepted answear i got this code to work for me:**

```
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
  $val=array();
  for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
    $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
    $val[] = $cell->getValue();
  }//close 2nd for loop
  //Create and convert xls date to php date
  $val[10] = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($val[10]);
  $val[10] = $val[10]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  //query stuff...
}//close first for loop
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No PHPExcel doesn't change it.... it already is a number

MS Excel stores dates/times as a serialized timestamp based on the number of days since 1st January 1900 (or 1st January 1904 if using the Mac calendar).... that value of `42285.47993055556` is the Excel serialized timestamp that corresponds to `2015-10-08 11:31:06`.
The cell where this value is stored then has a number format code that converts it to a human representation of that date/time. If you change that mask, it changes the visible appearance of the value, but the underlying serialized value remains the same.

If you do

```
$val[] = $cell->getFormattedValue();
```

then PHPExcel will apply the number format mask to that serialized date/timestamp, and return a string containing the human readable format of that date, based on the mask that was stored in the Excel file.

If you do

```
$val[] = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($cell->getValue());
```

then PHPExcel will return a unix timestamp that you can pass to the PHP `date()` function to format however you want

If you do

```
$val[] = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($cell->getValue());
```

then PHPExcel will return a PHP DateTime object that you can then format however you want using the DateTime object `format()` method